# Understanding Li-ion Battery(ICR18650-26H)

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

I trying to use a Li-ion Battery in my project. ICR18650-26H is suitable for my project(GPS data logger) I think. I am having hard time understanding one particular parameter in the specification document of the battery.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is the internal resistance of the battery a PTC in nature?
2. If that is the case, i dont have to use external thermistors to measure the temperature of the battery? Or can I use an external thermistor of my choosing?

Thanks

Comment: The PTC is a re-settable fuse that is built-in to the battery or battery pack. The battery resistance is probably a bit higher than the PTC resistance, but the resistance you see from the outside will be the sum of both (plus anything else that may be in series with the battery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the battery has a PTC protection device, the PTC acts as a self-resetting circuit breaker which limits the maximum current that can be drawn from the battery to a safe(er) level. If you want to measure the temperature you'll need a separate thermistor. Temperature measuring thermistors are NTC devices - their resistance goes down as they get hotter, PTCs are the opposite, their resistance goes up as they heat up, this is why they make good protection devices, if you try and draw more current, it heats up more driving it's resistance up, limiting the current - the PTC will be in series with the cell.